# Right place to set CorrelationManager.ActivityId in a ASP.net Web API service

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, nlog

We're using NLog in an ASP.net Web API service and as part of the layout we use `${activityid}`.

Now some of our consumers provide a Guid in the request header, that is a unique ID for the call on their side. So it would make sense to log this ID when given, so we can debug more easily.

When I want to set the `CorrelationManager.ActivityId` to the provided ID for all requests, where this header is given, what would be the best/earliest place to do so, so all following log entries will carry this Id instead of the automatically generated ActivityId?

Comment: Maybe hook up `Application_BeginRequest` in `Global.asax.cs`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Trace-Activity-Id-Layout-Renderer#example

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. It sets the value and a `Log.Debug` call in the same method records the correct Guid, but calls from the Controller log another Guid, it seems the `ActivityId` gets changed in between.

Comment: Currently I'm experimenting with another way: using the `${aspnet-request-headers}` layout renderer and setting the header manually in `Application_BeginRequest` if it is not provided. Not my dream solution, but at least it seems to work.

Comment: There is also [${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetTraceIdentifier-Layout-Renderer), though it requires IIS ETW feature enabled on ASP.NET Classic.

Comment: `${aspnet-request-headers:HeaderNames=JSNLog-RequestId:whenEmpty=${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by setting the `ActivityId` in `Application_BeginRequest` (Global.asax.cs) and using `${aspnet-request-headers}` and `whenEmpty` (thanks @Rolf Kristensen) in the NLog.config:

`${aspnet-request-headers:HeaderNames=My-Request-ID:ValuesOnly=true:whenEmpty=${activityid}}`

Also setting the `ActivityId` in parts of the Application, where there is no request.

So it is a fallback: If there is a "My-Request-ID" header, log this ID, if not log the `AcitivityId`.